# How do you patch update Android Studio (0.80 -> 0.81)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have Android Studio Beta v0.8.0 installed and downloaded v0.8.1 because the IDE won't automatically download and patch v0.80 with the new version. The preview series of Android Studio did that automatically.

From their webpage: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudiobetareleased it states:

> If you have already installed 0.8.0, you can patch update from 0.8.0 to 0.8.1.

I can't figure out how to patch Android Studio manually since there are no instructions. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. How can I patch it?

Comment: not fit for this site,probably!

Comment: @shekharsuman Seriously???  Where do you propose this question should be asked?

Comment: For now, I've temporarily installed AS Beta alongside the preview version.  I deleted the 0.8.0 version and just installed 0.8.1 without patching.  The 0.8.1 download is a complete package without the sdk and it looks like it will run as is.  You can use your existing sdk and the new AS Beta will allow the sdk manager to install all of the latest platforms.  Looks like manual install will do the trick for now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your update channel to "Beta Channel" and you are able to patch the update:

Configure > Settings > Updates > Beta Channel

Then check for updates and you can download the small upgrade without uninstalling or any other hassles.

On newer versions of Android Studio this has changed to:

Configure > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates > Beta Channel

Comment: Thanks for that, I hadn't thought of that.  So used to seeing the canary channel on the preview version.

Comment: Once I have "downloaded the small upgrade", what do I do with it? Just extract the files to the Android Studio installation directory and overwrite everything that already exists?