# can't update Android Studio to latest version

Tags: android, android-studio

when I select '`check for update`' following message is shown.
'`You already have the latest version of Android Studio (Preview) installed.`'
what should I do?
incidentally my Android Studio `version is 0.6.1`.
please teach me.

Comment: Starting with AS 0.9.11 you had to redownload and install on top of the old one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471646/how-do-you-patch-update-android-studio-0-80-0-81

Comment: The latest version is 1.0RC so you may as well just start from scratch,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete your Android Studio, just go:

1. `Help -> Check for update`, then it will show that "To configure automatic update settings, see the `Updates` dialog of your IDE Settings".
2. Click the Updates and switch the channel( I even go to the `Canary Channel` and get least `Android Studio 1.0 RC2`)

Answer (score 3):

There is no automated upgrade path from 0.6.1 to the current version (e.g., 0.8.14 on the beta channel). You will need to do a fresh install, deleting your existing Android Studio installation and installing a new one from [the Android Studio download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).